# What is webfilterdnsd process?

Tags: activity-monitor

What is webfilterdnsd process running on my machine? Its started by user "nobody". Not able to find any other information on it online. How can I get more information on processes running on my mac?

[image]

Comment: Are you running Parental Controls on your Mac?

Comment: No Parental controls is not running.

Comment: Well, I haven't been able to find exactly what it does, but some research states that "nobody" is a system user that OS X creates (so it's fine) and webfilterDNSd is a system process.  If Parental Controls are off, I'm not really sure why this is running, but it is most likely benign.

Comment: Sampling the process gives Process:         webfilterDNSd [112]
Path:            /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebContentAnalysis.framework/Versions/A/Resources/webfilterDNSd It looks like its associated with WebContentAnalysis.framework which is likely used by Parental Controls.

Answer (score 1):

Although it doesn't answer your question directly, the excellent

http://triviaware.com/macprocess/all

is a web resource that describes many Mac processes.

It describes webfilterDNSd as:

"Process is part of clean OS X install however there is no description available from credible sources at this moment. Use supplied link for related google search."

There's a comment section by which others that know might be able to answer your question.